# systemd journal is not stored in /var/log/journal and not persistent after reboots

Tags: systemd, journalctl

My embedded box is running Linux 5.15 with systemd 251 (251.2+).
I have configured persistent logging for journal.

```
/etc/systemd/journald.conf
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
```

Created folder /var/log/journal. This is mounted on mtd flash partition.

```
ls -alt /var/log/journal/
drwxr-sr-x    2 root     systemd-         0 Jan  1 00:03 2b4305f670484d1fa6b9c4deee336b91
```

Jouranld creates a folder under /var/log/journal but I dont see anything getting stored here ever.
**I don't see journal being persistent across reboots.**

Journal logs are kept only in /run/log/journal and this is tmpfs in the system and gets erased on each reboot.

I have tried `journalctl --flush` to see if anything gets pushed to inside /var/log/journal but nothing is stored apart form the folder name.
`journalctl --rotate` also has no impact.

I seem to be doing everything as per the journalctl documentation but still its not working.
Any help?

Comment: Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191313/414186). Not sure if it will be helpful. According to the thread the problem is about `machine-id`. Maybe [the Maluvel's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/624653/414186) is more useful.

Comment: the machine-id remains the same in my case. I came cross the thread.

Comment: You said that `/var/log/journal`  is mounted on mtd flash partition, right? What is its filesystem? I'm not really sure if the filesystem type is relevant for this but it should be useful to check that.

Comment: Its jffs2. It could be file system limitation. I have requested confirmation [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/25712)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file system in our case is jffs2.
Persistent journal would not work on jffs2. More details are in my [Github systemd issue #2571](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/25712).